# Why does the sequence ${1/n}$ not converge in the positive reals?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I'm reading Baby Rudin at the moment and it claims something remarkable. Consider the sequence

$$ x_n=\frac{1}{n}.$$

The book claims that this converges to zero in the reals:

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0.$$

It also claims that it does not converge like this in the positive reals. Why is this?

Comment: Where does it claim that?

Comment: Damn, sorry, I seem to have misread it. It claims something else which I cannot understand. Will edit the question.

Comment: "Positive reals" means $(0,\infty)$. The point to which the sequence would converge does not belong to the space.

Comment: Simply because $0$ is not positive. It's just a technicality: to converge in a particular space, the point of convergence also has to be in the space.

Comment: This is by definition, more or less. $0$ is *usually* not taken to be a positive or a negative number. So the sequence is Cauchy in the positive reals but the value it converges to is not in the positive reals.

Comment: Oh, then I seem to be a bit confused with the definition of converging *in* a space. Does a sequence converging in a space **only** imply that all elements in the sequence are in the space, along with the fact that the limit it converges to is also in the space?

Comment: If you look up the definition Rudin gives for convergence, I'll bet you'll find it stated exactly so.

Comment: @user161959 That is exactly correct. Just because things get close doesn't mean they converge. Convergence requires the thing they get close to to also be in the set.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because $0$ is not a positive real!

Answer (score 4):

the definition of the rudin book: "A sequence $\{p_n\}$ in a metric space $X$ is said to converge if there 
is a point $**p \in X**$ with the following property...$$\lim_{n\to\infty }\{p_n\}=p$$

how $0 \notin X=(0,\infty)$ then don't exist, a such $p\in(0,\infty)$